# Tab Bar hides when navigate to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a add button on my first view controller when I navigate to the second view controller the tab bar hides. I am using `prepareForSegue` method to navigate to second view controller. Here is my code of `prepareForSegue:`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddDoc" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let destinationViewController = viewController.topViewController as! CategoryViewController
        destinationViewController.doc = captureImageView.image
    }
}
```

And I used the present modally segue to navigate. I have both my view controller embedded in navigation controller. Thank you!

Comment: change the segue to show (push),

Comment: But it will not pass data. @SubhashSharma

Comment: Push will also call `prepareForSegue` just like modal presentation. So passing the data should not be a problem

Comment: It hides the tab bar at the bottom @BhumitMehta

Comment: What is your hierarchy ? Tabbar >> Navigationbar as first tab >> VC as rootVC of navigationbar ?? or do you have Navigationbar >> Tabbar as rootVC of navigationbar?

Comment: I have Tabbar >> Navigationbar as first tab >> VC as rootVC @BhumitMehta

Answer (score 0):

Just set the dest view controller's *hidesBottomBarWhenPushed* property with true. `destVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`